# Total fees paid by the student

Tags: mysql, sql

Write a query to display the student's ID and the total fees paid by each student. Give alias name to total fees as TOTALFEES. Sort the result based on student ID. 
I tried this but it returns student id multiple times with each course fees.I want the total fees per student id.
please anyone help

```
select s.studid,sum(c.fees) as TOTALFEES from course c,student s,registration r
where s.studid=r.studid and c.courseid=r.courseid
group by c.fees,s.studid
order by s.studid;
```

Answer (score 1):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

*Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

What you need is the right `GROUP BY`.  So:

```
select r.studid, sum(c.fees) as TOTALFEES
from course c join
     registration r
     on c.courseid = r.courseid
group by r.studid
order by r.studid;
```

You want one row per `studid`, so that is the only column in the `GROUP BY`.

Note that `studid` is in the `registration` table.  There is no need to `JOIN` to `student` to get it.

Answer (score 0):

How can you take studid from course?

```
SELECT studid,
       Sum(fees) AS TOTALFEES
FROM   student
       JOIN registration USING(studid)
       JOIN course USING(coursid)
ORDER  BY studid;
```

Try this.It might work